# PHP forking php-fpm with pcntl_fork()

Tags: php, fork

I'm forking with this code:

```
echo "1. posix_getpid()=".posix_getpid().", posix_getppid()=".posix_getppid()."\n";

$pid = pcntl_fork();
var_dump($pid);
if ($pid == -1) die("could not fork");

if ($pid) {
//parent
echo "2. pid=".$pid.", posix_getpid()=".posix_getpid().", posix_getppid()=".posix_getppid()."\n";
} else {
//child
$sid = posix_setsid();

if ($sid < 0)
exit;

echo "3. pid=".$pid.", posix_getpid()=".posix_getpid().", posix_getppid()=".posix_getppid()."\n";

$fp = fopen("/tmp/testfile", "w");
fwrite($fp, '$data');
fclose($fp);

}
```

For some reason sometimes the else block is sent to the browser, and sometimes the if ($pid) block is displayed.

What I'm trying to achieve is to send some response, and then continue processing after the connection with the client has closed. Then finally close after the post-request processing is finished. If I sleep in the child or parent the request hangs there.

Both parts are being executed though, it's just being weird in determining which on is sent to the browser.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [`ignore_user_abort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) instead.

Comment: Can I explicitly close the connection too? Because it seems that the connection to client is held until the user aborts.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you should use `fastcgi_finish_request()` to send the response to the browser, then continue working in the background. Keep in mind though, that this ONLY works when using PHP-FPM.

Note: the `fastcgi_finish_request()` function isn't documented in the PHP manual (see bug 61449) but the usage is pretty straight forward.

As for `ignore_user_abort()`, some comments on php.net suggest using the `Content-Length: 0` header with it, but this will cause problems when using SSL in conjunction with Internet Explorer.